# Bulma Navbar buttons are misplaced and I want them unhidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bulma

I am creating a navbar for mobile using Bulma. The HTML snippet I used from Bulma for the Navbar is misbehaving by aligning the buttons to the left instead of aligning them to the right. Moreover, I want those buttons to appear on small screens to the right without the Hamburger. Here is what it looks like on small and large screens. I have even tried using columns to align the buttons to the right and make their appearance possible on small screens.

[Small Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNcUr.png)

[Large Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DL9B.png)

Here's my code for Navbar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button is-primary navbar-end">
                <strong>Sign up</strong>
              </a>
              <a class="button is-light navbar-end">
                    Log in
                  </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `<div>` with a class of `"navbar-start"` that is not needed and you also need to get rid of `class="navbar-menu"` as Bulma automatically hides the right side on small devices with this class.

```
<div id="navbarBasicExample"> 
             <div class="navbar-end">
              <div class="navbar-item">
                <div class="buttons">
                  <a class="button is-primary navbar-end">
                    <strong>Sign up</strong>
                  </a>
                  <a class="button is-light navbar-end">
                        Log in
                      </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```